# Monopolistic Competition- productive efficiency

Tags: microeconomics

In my textbook, it says that monopolistic competition will never lead to productive efficiency (where $MC=AC$) in the short run and long run. I understand that they are meant to be producing at the profit-maximising level of output (where $MC=MR$), but all the diagrams showcase scenarios where the $AC$ curve is always positioned such that the points where MR=MC does not intersect where $MC=AC$.

My question is, is there any possibility that the profit-maximising level of output will also happen to be where we've achieved the lowest possible unit cost (lowest $AC$)? So that $MC=MR=AC$, and the firm can be both productively-efficient whilst also being profit-maximising? Why is this not possible?

Comment: Which textbook is this? Does it discuss monopolistic competition before it discusses perfect competition?

Answer (score 1):

Let $q$ denote the output of the firm, and let $\varepsilon_p(q)$ denote the elasticity of price w.r.t. quantity sold. We know that when profit is maximized
$$
|\varepsilon_p(q)| = \frac{p(q)-MC(q)}{p(q)}.
$$
We also know that in the long-run equilibrium firms have zero economic profit, i.e.
$$
AC(q) = p(q).
$$
Productive efficiency is achieved when $AC(q)$ is minimized, and at that point
$$
AC(q) = MC(q)
$$
holds as well. Combining these we get
$$
|\varepsilon_p(q)| = \frac{p(q)-MC(q)}{p(q)} = \frac{AC(q)-AC(q)}{p(q)} = 0.
$$
So the only case when all these properties coincide is when the quantity sold has no effect on the market price, i.e. when demand is perfectly elastic.

---

An explanation without the elasticity part: 
From the other two properties (long-run equilibrium and productive efficiency) we have 
$$
MC(q) = AC(q) = p(q).
$$
Together with profit maximization this implies that firms are price takers, $MR(q) = p(q)$, but since
$$
MR(q) = \frac{\text{d} \ p(q)q}{\text{d} \ q} = p(q) + p'(q)q
$$
this is only possible if $p'(q) = 0$, which again means that demand is perfectly elastic.

---

All the above assumed that the demand and inverse demand functions are continuously differentiable. You could have a situation with not perfectly elastic but kinked demand, where profit maximization occurs exactly at the kink. In this case $MR(q)$ does not exist at the point of profit maximization.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! It's actually a high school textbook for IB economics, so it doesn't go into a lot of detail, but yes perfect competition is introduced first.

Comment: I think my confusion is in the short run, when a firm (monopolistic competition) can produce abnormal profits, is it possible for the point where AC is minimised to also be the point where MC=MR. Maybe it would be clearer to me if I was working with more detailed text.

Comment: @rye This is exactly the question I have answered.